# Java remove duplicates from array using loops

Tags: java, arrays

This is my current attempt to remove duplicates from an array holding integers, but this does not give me any results. It simply prints out nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    public static void duplicate(int numbers[], int size)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        boolean duplicate = false;
        int b = 0;
        while (b < i){
          if (numbers[i] == numbers[b])
             duplicate = true;
          b++;}
        if (duplicate = false)
          System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");}
    }
```

Comment: this should work fine. just change = with == in the last if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void duplicate(int numbers[], int size)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    boolean duplicate = false;
    int b = 0;
    while (b < i){
      if (numbers[i] == numbers[b])
         duplicate = true;
      b++;}
    if (duplicate == false)
      System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");}
}
```

You need to use `==` not `=` in your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of `HashSet or LinkedHashSet to Preserve the ordering`

```
public void removeDupInIntArray(int[] ints){
    Set<Integer> setString = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<ints.length;i++){
        setString.add(ints[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(setString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best choice would be to use the Sets(Hash Linkedhash) so duplicates can be avoided