# Algorithm for removing duplicates from ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, duplicates

I have an `ArrayList<String>` that contains the following:

**2**#3#**1**#0

**1**#0#**4**#1

**9**#2#**5**#0

**4**#2#**3**#2

**1**#1#**2**#1

Output: 6 different numbers.

I'm trying to write an algorithm that removes duplicates of the highlighted numbers so I can then use a counter to see how many different numbers in total in all of those locations are.

I've tried many things including some of the following: [Java remove duplicates from array using loops][1], [Java - Removing duplicates in an ArrayList][2], the first option in [How to find duplicates in Java array?][3] and many more. I've spent at least 5-10h just trying to figure what I'm doing wrong, but I can not, so I've turned to you.

Most of the time the solutions I find online seem to work on simple stuff, but not in my case. In it, when I try to print the different characters, it always returns the wrong `int` numbers.

I've also tried, also tried separating each line of numbers into a different `int Array[]` and then comparing, but it just won't catch all the different values.

In another example where I had 5 different numbers in total, I kept getting "4 different" as a result, so I even tried `long n = ArrayList.stream().distinct().count();` **just to see** if I was doing something wrong, but even this thing returned "4 different" numbers.

I know the easiest way is using `Set` and `Map`, but I don't want that. I'd like to have an algorithm.

EDIT:

One of the many things I've tried is the following:

```
for (int m = 0; m < (size-1); m++){
        for (int j = m + 1; j < size; j++){
            if (ArrayList.get(j).charAt(0) != ArrayList.get(m).charAt(0)){
                continue;
            }
            current++;
            ArrayList.remove(j).charAt(0);
            j--;
            size--;
        }
    }
```

With this one, I'd have to use another one for the `ArrayList.get().charAt(4)`.

EDIT2:

I've found the following code [here][1], but how would it be implemented in this case?

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> uniquefy(ArrayList<T> myList) {

    ArrayList <T> uniqueArrayList = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){
        if (!uniqueArrayList.contains(myList.get(i))){
            uniqueArrayList.add(myList.get(i));
        }
    }

    return uniqueArrayList;
}
```

EDIT3:
I've found a possible solution, but it gives me an IndexOutOfBoundsException.
I've put the numbers **2, 1, 9, 4, 1** into `Array1` and **1, 4, 5, 3, 2** into `Array2`, but when I try to compare them, I get the mentioned error.

```
boolean stopSequence = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < Array1.length; i++){
        for (int a = 0; a < Array2.length && !stopSequence;){
            if (Array1[i] != Array2[a]){
                Array1[i] = 0;
                a++;
            }
            if (Array1[i] == Array2[a]){
                Array1[i] = 0;
                stopSequence = true;
            }
        }
        stopSequence = false;
    }

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998156/java-remove-duplicates-from-array-using-loops
[2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435156/java-removing-duplicates-in-an-arraylist
[3]: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.es/2015/06/3-ways-to-find-duplicate-elements-in-array-java.html
[4]: https://stackoverflo
```

w.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist?rq=1

Comment: What would be the result required for the given input example?

Comment: I would use a counter and print, in this case, "6 different numbers".

Comment: When you have code that is not working... Show it here. See [mcve]

Comment: What is your question exactly? We won't write the code for you, and you didn't post any. You're also rejecting the obvious solution consisting in putting all the numbers in a set, and then printing the size of the set. Why?

Comment: @GhostCat Ok. I'll put one of the "solutions" I've tried.

Comment: @DoombringerBG How would you check whether the number was taken or not using counter?

Comment: How are you representing highlighted numbers in the code?

Comment: @DoombringerBG you still have not posted a complete example, but just a piece of the code. Please post a complete example, together with input data.

Comment: I would concatenate all the strings, extract individual digits and store in a data structure and finally find the count of unique digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm is much simpler than what you think it is:

1. transform every string into a pair of characters
2. putting all the characters into a collection or stream that removes duplicates
3. counting the number of characters.

Here is a complete example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Duplicates {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("2#3#1#0",
                                          "1#0#4#1",
                                          "9#2#5#0",
                                          "4#2#3#2",
                                          "1#1#2#1");
        System.out.println(
            list.stream()
                .flatMapToInt(s -> IntStream.of(s.charAt(0), s.charAt(4)))
                .distinct()
                .count());
    }
}
```

EDIT: You seem to want to obey absurd restrictions, and thus neither use a Stream nor a Set, where these completely make sense. Here's code only using lists, but doing basically the same thing as above, but in a much less efficient way:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Duplicates {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("2#3#1#0",
                                          "1#0#4#1",
                                          "9#2#5#0",
                                          "4#2#3#2",
                                          "1#1#2#1");
        List<Character> uniqueChars = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : list) {
            Character c0 = s.charAt(0);
            Character c4 = s.charAt(4);

            if (!uniqueChars.contains(c0)) {
                uniqueChars.add(c0);
            }
            if (!uniqueChars.contains(c4)) {
                uniqueChars.add(c4);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(uniqueChars.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use `Stream`. I'm pretty sure it can all be done using just normal loops, because I've done similar things, just not when I've had 2 things in each string line that i need to compare individually to all the others.

Comment: Excellent solution! Streams just don't stop astounding me. +1

Comment: I was thinking of a similar solution, but the flatMapToInt was a really nice compact way of writing it.

Comment: @DoombringerBG you can apply the same algorithm with loops and a Set<Integer>. But unless you are constrained by your platform (android?), you'd better start learning streams, because they're very powerful and allow for concise, expressive and efficient code.

Comment: @JBNizet If I wanted to use Sets or Maps or Streams or w/e in this case, I wouldn't have asked what I asked.

Comment: So, using an ArrayList is fine, but using a Set is not? Although ArrayList is not the appropriate collection, but Set is? Why? Why do you absolutely want to obey such absurd constraints? Of course you can write an O(n^2) algorithms to remove duplicates from an ArrayList. But why would you do that when Set is easier and more efficient (O(n))? Anyway, see my edited answer.

Comment: @JBNizet I know, it's retarded not to use those, but I've no say in it. You think I like making my life miserable? Either way, your solution with the `List` seems to work, but I tried putting my `ArrayList` that contains all of those String lines, instead of the actual lines ""2#3#1#0", "1#0#4#1",  "9#2#5#0",  "4#2#3#2",  "1#1#2#1" " and it doesn't seem to work. How would I replace those with the `ArrayList` containing them?

Comment: @JBNizet The error I get when trying to put the ArrayList in place of those strings is "no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that ArrayList<String> conforms to String inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: String lower bounds: ArrayList<String>".

Comment: @JBNizet Never mind, I just had to put "List<String> list = ArrayList;". :D

Comment: @JBNizet Also, thank you kindly for the help. Saved my ass.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that difficult to count different numbers of the highlighted locations.you can use helper array called frequency array to get the expected result.

Try this simple algorithm using frequency array I think it worked perfectly for your case:

```
       ArrayList<String> numlist=new ArrayList<String>();
       int freq[] = new int [10];
       numlist.add("2#3#1#0");
       numlist.add("1#0#4#1");
       numlist.add("9#2#5#0");
       numlist.add("4#2#3#2");
       numlist.add("1#1#2#1");
       for(int i = 0; i < numlist.size(); i++){
           String row = numlist.get(i);          
           int numValue1 = Character.getNumericValue(row.charAt(0));
           int numValue2 = Character.getNumericValue(row.charAt(4));
           freq[numValue1]++;
           freq[numValue2]++;          
       }
       int count = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
           if(freq[i] > 0){
               count++;
           }
       }
       System.out.println(count + " different numbers");
```

**Output**:

```
6 different numbers
```

Comment: A little bit too late, but I think I would've used this, if JB Nizet didn't beat you to it. Either way, I'm thankful for your help. :3

Comment: No problem.
you're welcome. don't make your problem more complicated keep it simple as possible. try to break it down to a simpler pieces in order to get the expected result in clean way.

Answer (score 1):

Another option with bit masks:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> arrayList = Arrays.asList("2#3#1#0", "1#0#4#1", "9#2#5#0", "4#2#3#2", "1#1#2#1");
    int mask = 0;
    for(String s : arrayList) { // Place the bits
        mask = mask | (1 << Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0))) | (1 << Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(4)));
    }
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) { // count the bits
        counter += (mask & (1 << i)) == 1 << i ? 1 : 0;
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

Output:

```
6
```

This relies on the bit mask which is at the end of the execution of the code:

```
1000111110
```

Possibly this is faster than most solutions, since it does not rely on conventional data structures.

Comment: Never seen bit masks in my life, but it does seem easy to read. :3

Comment: Just a question to whoever sees this: is there a potential way to have a "faster" solution for this problem which uses less memory? How does this compare in terms of efficiency with other solutions displayed above?

Answer (score 0):

Well, a good practice is always to **divide the problem into smaller parts**:

For example, a good design would be a class with these members:

- `digits`: This is an instance variable of array of ints to contain the number of times each digit was repeated. It must be pre-sized to the maximum allowed digit (I guess that is **9**).
- `differentDigits`: The is an instance variable to contain the number of different digits.
- `processList`: This method shall receive the list to browse it and call `processItem` for each item.
- `processItem`: This method shall receive an item String and parse the digits according to the specified format (through `StringTokenizer`, for example), and call `storeDigit` for each required digit.
- `storeDigit`: This method shall receive an int and use it to index the instance array `digits`, and increment the indexed position. If the indexed position was 0, it should also increment `differentDigits`.